# How do I set align to center for a div with position fixed?

Tags: css, css-position

+It's workging now

I'm trying to have a bar on the bottom of the page with a width of 1024px aligned on the center.

I already tried margin:0 auto and text-align:center.None worked.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
  .bf_footer{
     position:fixed; 
     bottom:0px; 
     width:1024px;
     background:#000;
     height:20px;
     padding-bottom:5px;
     left:50%; 
     margin-left:-512px;
   }
</style>



<div class="bf_footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript for calculation of the position like this:

```
$("div.bf_footer").css({
   left: ($(window).width() / 2) - ($("div.bf_footer").width() / 2)
});
```

Comment: Cool Jin. Tnx for the fast reply. It worked fine like that, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with pure css. Would you know how to do that as well?

Comment: Actually it didnt work. Here is my code:
  
    <script>
    $("div.bf_footer").css({
    left: ($(window).width() / 2) - ($("div.bf_footer").width() / 2)
});
    </script>
    <div class="bf_footer"></div>

Comment: @ViniciusSantana Problem is with fixed position, in this case must say exactly where element is (left, top). Auto center is able with margin: x auto; but position cannot be fixed

Answer (score 1):

you can siply have a parent element and set  `margin:0 auto;` then you can make your effect.

```
<div style="background:blue;height:0px;width:300px;margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="bf_footer"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.bf_footer{
     position:absolute; 
          width:300px;
     background:#000;
     height:20px;
     bottom:0; 
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MvPsd/

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I have found to do this is:

```
 <style>
     .divtobealigned{             
         position:fixed;
         background:grey;
         width:400px;
         left:50%;
         margin-left:-200px; <!-- Half of the width-->

     }
 </style>
 <div class="divtobealigned">Div with position absolute centered on the screen.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/9Jk9k/